# How do we know that P != LINSPACE without knowing if one is a subset of the other?

Tags: computational-complexity

I've seen that P != LINSPACE (by which I mean SPACE(n)), but that we don't know if one is a subset of the other.

I assume that means that the proof must not involve showing a problem that's in one class but not the other, so how else would you go about proving it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Suppose by contradiction that P=SPACE(n).  Then there exists an algorithm to simulate an n-space Turing machine in (say) n<sup>c</sup> time, for some constant c.  But this means that there exists an algorithm to simulate an *n<sup>2</sup>*-space Turing machine in n<sup>2c</sup> time.  Therefore SPACE(n<sup>2</sup>) is also contained in P.  So

P = SPACE(n) = SPACE(n<sup>2</sup>).

But SPACE(n) = SPACE(n<sup>2</sup>) contradicts the Space Hierarchy Theorem.  QED

(Notice that in this proof, we showed neither that P is not contained in SPACE(n), nor that SPACE(n) is not contained in P!  We only showed that *one or the other* must be true, by using the different closure properties of polynomial time and linear space.  It's conjectured that P and SPACE(n) are incomparable.)

Comment: This proof works also for showing that NP is not equal to SPACE(n).



Comment: Or, indeed, in SPACE(n^k) for fixed k.

Comment: It is not clear to me, whether the "algorithm" in the second sentence is meant to be universal, or whether each n-space machine translates to a different PTIME machine.  But then there's a bigger jump.  I can see how then to simulate any $n^2$-space machine in time $n^{c}.2^{O(n)}+c$, but not in $n^{2c}$-time.  Can you please elaborate that step or cite?

Comment: Jirka: Sorry, just saw your comment!  All you need to do is feed your $n^2$-space machine to your algorithm for $n$-space machines.  But don't tell the algorithm you're giving it an $n^2$-space machine!  Just tell it you're giving it an $N$-space machine, but choose $N$ so that it happens to equal $n^2$. :-)

Comment: Taken literally, the second sentence of this answer is plain wrong. The easiest way to avoid plain wrong sentences would be to explicitly indicate the dependence on the Turing machine $M$: "Then there exists an algorithm to simulate an $n$-space Turing machine $M$ in (say) $n^{c(M)}$ time, for some constant $c(M)$.  But this means that there exists an algorithm to simulate an $n^2$-space Turing machine $M'$ in $(n^2)^{c'(M')}$ time." Alternatively, one can distinguish explicitly between complexity classes and languages, like done in the other answers.

Comment: @ScottAaronson ping (see also the two other answers)

Answer (score 10):

I think I spotted a problem with the above proof by Scott. If P=SPACE($n$) implied that there's an algorithm to simulate an n-space Turing machine in (say) $n^c$ time, for some constant $c$, it would also imply that there's an algorithm in $n^c$ time to simulate all polynomial time Turing machines, and that P=TIME($n^c$), which contradicts the Time Hierarchy Theorem. But this problem can be fixed, of course:

Suppose that P=SPACE($n$). For contradiction with the Space Hierarchy Theorem, we'd like to show that every language in SPACE($n^2$) can be reduced in polynomial time to SPACE($n$). We will do this using the padding argument.

Let $L$ ∈ SPACE($n^2$), $M$ a Turing machine with space complexity $n^2$ for the language $L$. Let $L'$ be the “padded” version of $L$ defined as the set of words of the form $x01^{|x|^2}$ for each $x ∈ L$. Now $L'$ is in SPACE($n$) because for an input of size $n$, no more than $\sqrt{n}$ characters are the original input and we can run the simulation of the original machine $M$ using space $n$.

A reduction from $L$ to $L'$ can be easily done in polynomial time, hence P=SPACE($n$)=SPACE($n^2$), and we get the desired contradiction with the Space Hierarchy Theorem.

Comment: That's not a problem.  The whole argument is proof by contradiction; you've just provided a different contradiction.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that P=SPACE($n$) does not imply the existence of an algorithm to simulate any $n$-space Turing machine in $n^c$ time, hence the rest of the proof is irrelevant, not “just a difference contradiction”.

Comment: @Tomáš: I first thought that @ScottAaronson may have assumed a universal (multitape) Turing machine that would be able to simulate any $n$-space machine with overhead that keeps the execution, say, in $2n$.  But that also cannot be the full story, because the code of a particular LINSPACE machine can occupy more than $n^c$ tape fields and thus not meet the time limit without some further trick.

Answer (score 3):

In comparison to the existing answers, the following answer tries to better distinguish between complexity classes, languages in a complexity class, and words over the alphabet of a language.

---

Assume $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{SPACE}(n)$. Then we can show that $L\in\mathsf{SPACE}(n^2)$ implies $L\in \mathsf{P}$. This is equivalent to $\mathsf{SPACE}(n^2)\subset \mathsf{P}=\mathsf{SPACE}(n)$, which contradicts the Space Hierarchy Theorem.

Let's show that $L\in\mathsf{SPACE}(n^2)$ would imply $L\in \mathsf{P}$, if $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{SPACE}(n)$. Let $L \in \mathsf{SPACE}(n^2)$ be a language over the alphabet $\Sigma_L$, i.e. $L\subset \Sigma_L^*$. WLOG assume $\Sigma_L=\{0,1\}$. We define the "padding" function $f_L:\Sigma_L^*\to \Sigma_L^*$ via $f_L(w)=w01^{|w|^2-|w|}$, where $|w|$ is the length of the word $w$. Let $L':=f_L(L)$. We have $w\in L \Leftrightarrow f_L(w)\in L'$, because $f_L$ is injective. We have $L' \in \mathsf{SPACE}(n)$, because $|f_L(w)|=|w|^2+1$. (This point is already elaborated in the other answers.)
We can now conclude $L\in \mathsf{P}$ based on our assumption $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{SPACE}(n)$ and the fact that $f_L(w)$ can be computed in time $O(|w|^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume by contradiction that P=SPACE(n). This means polynomial-time reduction is equivalent to linear space reduction. Therefore TQBF is PSPACE-complete in terms of both reductions. Since TQBF $\in$ SPACE(n), we conclude that PSPACE=SPACE(n)=P, contradicting the Space Hierarchy Theorem.